# How can I make div that contains images to have fixed size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project, and I'm trying to get a fixed div container so that I can have all pictures in the div container and they will have the same size. I tried many suggested ways, but somehow it does not do anything to my div container. Nothing at all. I'm not 100% sure but I assume it's because I use bootstrap? Why am I not able to change the size?

```
[image1][image2]
[   image3     ]
```

This is how I try to have a fixed size div, but what my css does is still:

```
[image1][image2]
   [image3]
```

```css
.imagesContainer {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imagesContainer img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="album">

  <div class="imagesContainer">
      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
          <div class="col-4 px-2">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid" alt="1">
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 px-2">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid" alt="1">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagesContainer">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col mt-3"></div>
          <div class="col mt-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="3"></div>
          <div class="col mt-3"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use images from for example placeholder.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to stick to Bootstrap, this solution might help

```css
.album {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imagesContainer {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imagesContainer img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="album">
  <div class="imagesContainer">
      <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col px-2">
              <img src="https://fujifilm-x.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/x-t30_sample-images02.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="1">
          </div>
          <div class="col px-2">
              <img src="https://fujifilm-x.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/x-t30_sample-images02.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="1">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col"><img src="https://fujifilm-x.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/x-t30_sample-images02.jpg" alt="3"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use your own styles rather than bootstraps. So you can have 3 separate divs inside the main div and set the images as the background images. With the three separate divs, you can use display- flex on the overall image container and have them be responsive and meet your designs. Here is what I mean and I hope it helps.

```
.imagesContainer {
  width: 800px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

> //overall image container

```
.imagesContainer {
  width: 800px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

> //individual image div

```
  .imageDiv {
  background-image: url(${Image}); 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
  flex: 1 1 400px; 
}
```

> You can add an additional class name to the last image container and have it specifically change the background size to contain as so if you want it to stretch and fill out the empty space

```
    .lastImageContainer{
  background-size: contain;
}
```